# proof of the inequality?

Tags: inequality

prove that $$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\le\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|} $$
To solve this I assumed if $x,y$ are of opposite signs and  $x\gt y$ then  $|x+y|\le |x|$.
we get 
$$\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}\ge\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}$$
how to proceed further..
as answered by hans 
 to prove that the function $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$$ is monotonous ,$y\ge x$ then 
$$\frac{1}{1+y}\le\frac{1}{1+x}$$
$$1-\frac{1}{1+y}\ge 1-\frac{1}{1+x}$$
$$\frac{y}{1+y}\ge\frac{x}{1+x}$$
further $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$ and using the above inequality 
One gets

$$\frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}\ge\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}$$

Comment: See also: [Prove $\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}<\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194314) and [Is $\frac{\vert x+y\vert}{1+\vert x+y\vert}\leq\frac{\vert x\vert}{1+\vert x\vert}+\frac{\vert y\vert}{1+\vert y\vert}$ true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/983043). (And several other posts.)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in three steps:

1. Prove or quote that $|x+y| \le |x| + |y|$.
2. Prove that $f(z) = \frac{z}{z+1}$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$. This can be done with Calculus or with an algebra step.
3. Prove that $\frac{a+b}{1+a+b} \le \frac{a}{1+a} + \frac{b}{1+b}$ for all $a, \, b \ge 0$. That is also an algebra step.

Then put these three arguments together to make a proof.

Comment: It doesn't require calculus to show that $z\gt w\gt0$ implies $z/(z+1)\gt w/(w+1)$.

Comment: Indeed, all this can be done with algebraic manipulations. I'll change the post.

Comment: yes it can be proved easily through inequalities @BarryCipra

Answer (score 3):

All you need is the triangle inequality: $\vert x+y\vert \leq \vert x\vert +\vert y\vert$.

Now, if LHS=$0$, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we have

$$\frac{1}{\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert}\le\frac{1}{\vert x+y\vert }\Rightarrow 1+\frac{1}{\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert}\le 1+\frac{1}{\vert x+y\vert }\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\vert x+y\vert }}\le \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert}}\Rightarrow \frac{\vert x+y\vert }{1+\vert x+y\vert }\le \frac{\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert }{1+\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert }=\frac{\vert x\vert}{1+\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert }+\frac{\vert y\vert }{1+\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert }\le \frac{\vert x\vert}{1+\vert x\vert }+\frac{\vert y\vert }{1+\vert y\vert }$$.

Comment: $\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\le\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$ is to be proved

Comment: I added the extra step, which I thought was obvious. Thanks.

Comment: but how this trivial step is done,can you explain @chilango

Comment: you are removing a positive number from each denominator, so each term increases

Comment: can you explain in detail @chilango

Comment: Yes of course they will but there should be a way to prove it

Comment: Are you joking? If $x,y>0$ then $x+y>y\Leftrightarrow 1/(x+y)<1/y$