# how to prove the following inequality by using real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

how to prove this inequality by real anlysis

$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|} \leq \frac{|x|}{1+|x|} + \frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$

I finally came with the following inequality. but I dont know what to do after that

$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|} \leq \frac{|x|}{1+|x+y|} + \frac{|y|}{1+|x+y|}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}<\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194314/prove-fracab1ab-fraca1a-fracb1b)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563491/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/983043/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx%2By%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cx%2By%7C%7D%20%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cx%7C%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B%7Cy%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cy%7C%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function $f(t) = \frac{t}{1+t}$ is increasing for $t\geq 0$.

So, using

- $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ and
- $\frac{|x|}{1+|x|} \geq \frac{|x|}{1+|x|+|y|}$ and $\frac{|y|}{1+|y|} \geq \frac{|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}$

you get

$$\frac{|x|}{1+|x|} + \frac{|y|}{1+|y|} \geq \frac{|x| + |y|}{1+|x| +|y|} \stackrel{f\; increasing}{\geq}\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t):= \frac{t}{1+t}$ for $t \ge 0.$ Show that $f$ is increasing. Since $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$, we get

$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}=f(|x+y|) \le f(|x|+|y|)=\frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}$.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the triangle inequality.

$$
\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x|+|y|} \leq \frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}=\frac{|x|}{1+|x|+|y|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}\leq \frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}
$$

Comment: Best answer +1.

Comment: The task is to estimate  $\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|} $ and that is $\ge \frac{|x+y|}{1+|x|+|y|} $ ...

Comment: You are right, I missread the initial post.